# How to work on same Python Jupyter Notebook on two different Macbook Pro

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have two MacBook that I leave one of them in my office and the other one I keep it home. How can I sync python notebooks or use the same jupyter notebooks on different computers? What would be the easiest way?

Thank you!

Comment: Personally I use [syncthing](https://syncthing.net)

Comment: Digital Ocean droplets are pennies per month if you shut them down after use.